# Why is Mongoose Model.findOneAndReplace() not in @types/mongoose?

Tags: typescript, mongoose

The mongoosejs documentation details the [Model.findOneAndReplace()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndReplace) method.  However, this method does not appear to be included in the types present in [@types/mongoose from the DefinitelyTyped repo](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mongoose/index.d.ts).  This is surprising, because the methods findOneAndUpdate(), findOneAndRemove() and findOneAndUpdate() are all present.

Am I missing something obvious?  Does anyone know of a reason this might be excluded?

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer, but posting workaround here in case useful for others: I ended up using findOneAndReplace on the model collection instead. This directly exposes MongoDB methods, (and types).

```
model.collection.findOneAndReplace(filter, replacement, options, callback)
```

See here for method details
http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#findOneAndReplace